# How to use a note from the Line Item Model

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

**Working with the example Commerce templates.** In the cart template there is an example for adding a note. https://craftcommerce.com/docs/line-item-model#note

The code for this form:

```
<form class="shopForm" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/updateLineItem">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="shop/cart">
<input type="hidden" name="lineItemId" value="{{ item.id }}">
{{ getCsrfInput() }}

<div class="field">
    <label for="note">Note</label>
    <input type="text" size="20" name="note" value="{{ item.note }}">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="qty">Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" name="qty" min="1" value="{{ item.qty }}">
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline" value="Update">
```

Very useful but after submitting the form, how can we display this later on in the ordering process? For example on a receipt or the order overview. Also can we view this in the Commerce back end? I was not able to find …

Can anybody shed some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The example template show how to display the note, but here is the jist of it:

```
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
 {{item.qty }} x {{ item.description }} - {{ item.note }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: take a look at the line item model: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/line-item-model

Comment: Thank you Luke, yes I checked the docs as you can see by the link. Also can we see a note in the back end?